# Find indices in numpy arrays consisting of lists where element is in list

Tags: python, numpy

So I have a numpy array containing lists (of various lengths) which consist of strings. I'd like to find all rows where a certain string appears in, e.g. I want to find all numpy array indices for which the corresponding list contains the string 'hello'.
I thought I could simply use

```
np.where('hello' in np_array)
```

but unfortunately this just results in an empty numpy array. Any ideas?

Comment: Numpy is not a good storage format for ragged arrays such as the one you describe.

Comment: Beware of the answers.  `np.vectorize`, even when it works, is **not** a performance tool.  Read all of its docs!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np
np_arr = np.array([['hello', 'salam', 'bonjour'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['hello']])

vec_func = np.vectorize(lambda x: 'hello' in x)
ind = vec_func(np_arr)
```

Output:

```
#Ind: 
array([ True, False,  True])

# np_arr[ind]:
array([list(['hello', 'salam', 'bonjour']), list(['hello'])], dtype=object)
```

However, if you wish to get the output as a list of integers for indices, you might use:

```py
np.where(vec_func(np_arr))

#(array([0, 2], dtype=int64),)
```

Comment: I'm assuming from the question that the output is meant to be a list of integers, so you might want to post-process your output with `np.where`.

Comment: @alani Thanks for bringing that up. Added to the answer.

Comment: One can also use `np.frompyfunc` as a lower level method for these types of stuff.

Comment: Thank you! Is there also a way to find the index of the string itself inside the list, too, so in your example the output would be [(0,0), (2,0)]?

Answer (score 1):

Following @aminrd's answer, you can also use `np.isin` instead of Python's `in`, which gives you the benefit of returning a boolean numpy array representing where the string `hello` appears.

```
import numpy as np

myarray = np.array(
    [["hello", "salam", "bonjour"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["hello"]], dtype=object
)

ids = np.frompyfunc(lambda x: np.isin(x, "hello"), 1, 1)(myarray)

idxs = [(i, np.where(curr)[0][0]) for i, curr in enumerate(ids) if curr.any()]
```

Result:

```
>>> print(ids)
    [array([ True, False, False]) array([False, False, False]) array([ True])]
>>> print(idxs)
    [(0, 0), (2, 0)]
```

**EDIT**: If you want to avoid the explicit loop, you could pad the array with 0 (same as `False`) and then use numpy's broadcasting normally (this is necessary since `ids` becomes an `object` array with shape `(3,)`)

```
>>> padded_ids = np.column_stack((itertools.zip_longest(*ids, fillvalue=0)))
>>> print(np.stack(np.where(padded_ids), axis=1))
    [[0 0]
     [2 0]]
```

Keep in mind padding methods usually have some kind of a loop somewhere, so I don't think you can totally get away from it.

Comment: Is there a way that avoids the explicit loop in Python (list comprehension)?

Comment: Thanks. I thought of something so I also posted it, but haven't benchmarked it or anything. I'll leave that to the OP... he has various options now.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the answer about `np.vectorize` in order to answer the additional question about returning also the index within each list (asked by the OP as a comment under the accepted answer), you could perhaps define a function which returns the index number or -1, and then vectorize that.  You can then post-process the return from this vectorized function, to obtain both types of required indices.

```py
import numpy as np

myarr = np.array([['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
                  ['quux'],
                  ['baz', 'foo']])

def get_index(val, lst):
    "return the index in a list, or -1 if the item is not present"
    try:
        return lst.index(val)
    except ValueError:
        return -1

func = lambda x:get_index('foo', x)

list_indices = np.vectorize(func)(myarr)  # [0 -1 1]
valid = (list_indices >= 0)  # [True False True]

array_indices = np.where(valid)[0]   # [0 2]
valid_list_indices = list_indices[valid]  # [0 1]

print(np.stack([array_indices, valid_list_indices]).T)
# [[0 0]    <== list 0, element 0
#  [2 1]]   <== list 2, element 1
```